# matlab, how to export text and numerical data to a excel csv file?

Tags: excel, matlab, text, csv, export

When I use the code below. I get the numerical data exported correctly however the first row is blank when there should be titles(headers) on the first row of each column. Any solutions?

```
clc 
clear

filename = 'file.csv'; 
fileID = fopen(filename,'wt');
%**************************************************************************
%Sample data (note sample data are transposed row, i.e. columns) 

sample1 = [1,2,3,4]';
sample2 = [332.3, 275.8, 233.3, 275]';
sample3 = [360, 416.7, 500, 360]';
sample4= [-0.9, -0.9, -0.9, -0.9]';
sample5 = [ 300000, 0, 0, 0]';

A ={'text1','text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5'}; %'

%***************************************************************************
%write string to csv

[rows, columns] = size(A);
for index = 1:rows    
    fprintf(fileID, '%s,', A{index,1:end-1});
    fprintf(fileID, '%s\n', A{index,end});
end 

fclose(fileID);

%***************************************************************************
%write numerical data to csv

d = [sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5];

csvwrite(filename, d, 1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are erasing strings when writing  numerical data ,run your script just up to numerical data - it works fine. Simply switch order of operations- first write numbers, and then write strings, it will work.

EDIT:
Solution above won't work because writing string overwrites previously written numerical data, simpler and more intuitivesolution would be to replace

```
csvwrite(filename, d, 1);
```

by

```
dlmwrite(filename, d,'-append', 'delimiter', ',');
```

in original example

Comment: the header works fine but the data doesn't get written correctly. I only get 2 rows of random data

Comment: True, it overwrites numerical data, it looks like dlmwrite is better option anyways...

Comment: did you have any luck in getting both text and numerical data to appear correctly on a csv file? I can get either or. But not both correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if I just replace csvwrite(filename, d, 1); by dlmwrite(filename, d,'-append', 'delimiter', ','); in your original example (without modifying anything else) - it appears correctly.

Comment: works perfect. thanks a lot. I will have to look up dlmwrite to understand what it did. appreciate it!